# bearer token undefined with global axios config

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I created a Vue app using Axios. I installed Axios via Vue UI dependency installation. In my **main.js** file I added a global configuration

```
import Vue from "vue";
import "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000";
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`;
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

When I want to `signOut` I execute this

```
signOut: async function() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/users/signout");
    // go on
  } catch (err) {
    // err handling
  }
}
```

but the post headers return an undefined token `Bearer undefined`. So I removed this line

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`;
```

from the **main.js** file and used this code

```
signOut: async function() {
  try {
    const request = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/users/signout"
    });
    request.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`;
    const response = await request.post();
    // go on
  } catch (err) {
    // err handling
  }
}
```

and this works fine. The `Authorization` header got setup correctly. Why does it work now? How can I fix the first approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are setting the authorization header in your `main.js` it will be executed once when the app start. If in your `localStorage` that token is not present it will be `undefined` and will stay that way until a request has it's own token. Now in the second approach you have your token present in your `localStorage`, and so it will correctly set the header.

In your first approach you can fix this by removing that `Authorization` header assignment and assigning the token in your requests directly or create a function that will assign the default header auth whenever the token from the server changes (or is removed).

### Update: A cleaner example using redirect interceptors

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const auth = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth;
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error),
);
```

This way before each request our token will be re-read from localStorage and the updated Bearer token will be set in the header.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to structure this in a bigger application? My current approach is to check `const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt')` and set `axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwt` before each call, which doesn't look clean.

Comment: @WatermelonSugar I updated my answer with an example using request interceptors which hopefully will help you.

Comment: This example looks good. I have edited it a little bit, because in the case of login, when no token is available, the string "Bearer null" would cause an error, so its better to do a check inside config